# NodeJS CryptoJS returns different AES-128-CBC encrypted value when using CryptoJS library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I've been using this code in NodeJS to encrypt/decrypt using AES-128-CBC:

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

var plaintext = 'TEST50';
var key = 'TXRZ3jThBP2dWnUN';
var iv = '2Mr9ca8KFEdAFGua';

key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC}).ciphertext.toString(
    CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log(encrypted);


var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    iv: iv,
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log(decrypted);
```

Encrypted: **Je0mn7zUeYZ/4ZswNesNhQ==**

Any tips or recommendations to solve this? Thanks!

I tried running the same code in Javascript and got a different encrypted value: **G7Tvk9YMCUYRS7iRzE1U/g==**

I'm expecting that the encrypted value should be the same in NodeJS since I can decrypt encrypted values from NodeJS in my Javascript code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you use the same version of crypto-js and use the same padding method in JavaScript and Node.js, `padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7`

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js'); //crypto-js": "4.0.0"

var plaintext = 'TEST50';
var key = 'TXRZ3jThBP2dWnUN';
var iv = '2Mr9ca8KFEdAFGua';

key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString();

console.log(encrypted); // Je0mn7zUeYZ/4ZswNesNhQ==


var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(decrypted); // TEST50
```

try in chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var plaintext = 'TEST50';
  var key = 'TXRZ3jThBP2dWnUN';
  var iv = '2Mr9ca8KFEdAFGua';

  key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }).toString();

  console.log(encrypted);

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
  }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

  console.log(decrypted);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using your code and it generates the same encrypted values. Do you have a source for CryptoJS that I can use for plain Javascript? I tried using the ones from CDN but I'm encountering this error:  Execution of JS-AES-128-CBC failed with error: Javascript runtime error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "lib" from undefined. (aes.js:19)"

Comment: @ryanangelooo, Can you tell me how to you use this CDN lib as I can get the value normally even in Chrome? please do not worry. We can discuss and solve problem together.

Comment: Hello. After further attempts, I managed to use the library but it's returning a different value: G7Tvk9YMCUYRS7iRzE1U/g==

Comment: @ryanangelooo, I used JS in Chrome and got the same value ​​as Node.js. can you tell me more about how you did it

Comment: @ryanangelooo copy the following code below try in Chrome and run it on https.//jsfiddle.net you can see that the result of this operation is consistent with node.js.

Comment: OMG. It worked! Thank you so much my friend. It was returning a different value because I forgot to retrieve the values of the IV and Key but thank you so much for teaching me!

Comment: Hahahahh, congratulations